How do I get my shape to glow, but still have detail?
I am making a fanmade K-pop lightstick for one of my favorite groups but I struggled with the top. It is supposed to be a glowing pink rose.
It is supposed to not glow, but when turned on it will let out a light glow.
I tried many ways to do this, making transparent textures, and using emission, but those either didn't work or lost all of the detail in the rose, which I still want to keep.

This is a reference of roughly what I want it to look like. I want it to kinda look like rubber or plastic with a light in the inside.


Hello do you have a reference image of the kind of effect you want?
